# How to merge two databases with differences in structure?

Tags: mysql

I have two versions of the same mysql database, which were split 6-8 months ago. Let us call them **versionA** and **versionB**.

**versionA** is on the production server which is constantly updated with data: .
**versionB** is a development  version which has some structural difference from **versionA** (some new tables added, some fields added to existing tables, some indexes added, some datatypes changed, some relations changed. All changes in **versionB** since the split are documented).

It appears that **versionA** had also some minor structural changes since the split, but they are undocumented.

## The goal:

To have all data from versionA merged into the structure of versionB. Some data from versionB also has to be preserved, but in case of conflict, versionA takes precedence.

Is there some tool that may help to automate the task? The tables have hundreds of thousands of records.

Comment: your production database was subject to unknown and undocumented changes? Nice.

Comment: @ADyson the production database is beyond our control; the client does not keep documentation from other developers.

Comment: Your client modified a database which you supplied, without your consent? In my experience, that kind of thing generally voids the support agreement. Or is this something which you intend them to do, but they just didn't document it?

Comment: Anyway I think you just have to write a migration script. I'm pretty sure if you search there are some schema comparison tools out there which might help identify the structural differences and maybe even script the necessary changes. They certainly exist for MS-SQL, maybe for MySQL too. After that it's really up to you to write meaningful scripts which will mutate the data from the old format to the new. Once you have a script which acts on a table, the number of rows involved isn't hugely relevant, other than for estimating timescales for the execution of the process.

Comment: @ADyson We are gradually taking over a project that was previously maintained by multiple developpers and no documentation, hence the problems

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense, I see your difficulty in that respect.